# My enclosed shortcode is setting the content parameter to an empty string

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm registering a shortcode with the following:

```
class Resource extends Shortcode
{
    public function action($atts, $content = "broken")
    {
        $markup = "<span id='examp'> $content </span>";

        return $markup;
    }
}

$resource = new Resource;
$resource->register();
```

in `$resource->action(...)` $content is being set to empty string regardless of the value in the shortcode.

The full code samples can be found for Shortcode and Resource

- [here](https://gist.github.com/nathanmann/9266745) and [here](https://gist.github.com/nathanmann/9266762) respectively.

I'm having literally no other problems with this. The $attr parameter is exactly as it should be and the only thing displayed is the $content value with no additional markup.
If this isn't enough information I'll share the repository - just let me know if it'd help.

Example input:

```
asdf[resource_download]abc[/resource_download]asdf
```

Expected Ouput:

```
asdf<span id='examp'>abc</span>asdf
```

Actual Output:

```
asdfabcasdf
```

Comment: You have not posted the code where exactly you calling `$resource->action(...)` ? And how exactly you calling it ?

Comment: It's a shortcode. WP is calling it. I've pasted links to the only two relevant code files in their entirety in the body of the question exactly as a I said I did.

Comment: And what `var_dump($markup);exit;` gives you ?

Comment: How it could be an empty span ? While you get `abc` in your final output.

Comment: The problem is most likely being caused by stealShortcode I'm working on troubleshooting it.

Comment: Yes, it seems that my empty content value is being caused by stealShortcode, however my action does not seem to be run without stealShortcode being called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48954/discussion-between-rikesh-and-uahta)

Comment: As we can read in the chat, you found an answer. Please post it so that futher readers can read the answer in a simpler way then reading the chat history and to show that the question is answered.

Comment: I had forgotten about this, let me see if I can't get @Rikesh to add an answer to this.

Comment: @uɐɥʇɐᴎ - just posted your solution as answer. Feel free to edit it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @uɐɥʇɐᴎ combined *[efforts](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48954/discussion-between-rikesh-and-uahta)* the problem we found was,

`stealshortcode` method is being called for another short-code class (Video as opposed to Resource). Video is setting that pattern to match all `[(.*?)]` which is setting the content to null before Resource has a chance to receive it.

Basically `stealshortcode` is called from the parent class which clear's the shortocde data.